# How to Fix "Column is invalid because its not contained in aggregate function or GROUP By clause"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to extract data from two tables that counts the number of orders that each client has placed. The SQL below works fine without the `S.Name` in the `SELECT`, but I would like the Name of the client in the output which is more meaningful than their StoreID. When I add S.Name, I get the following error:

> Column 'uStores.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT O.StoreID, COUNT(O.StoreID) AS OrderCount, S.Name
FROM Orders AS O
JOIN Stores AS ON O.StoreID = S.StoreID
GROUP BY O.StoreID
ORDER BY OrderCount DESC
```

How do I make this query work?

Comment: Group by O.StoreID and S.Name

Comment: Did you look at any of the related questions that undoubtedly came up when typing this title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to include *all* non-aggregated columns in the group by list; you've selected `S.Name`, which is not an aggregate but not in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT O.StoreID, COUNT(O.StoreID) AS OrderCount, S.Name
FROM Orders AS O
JOIN Stores AS S ON O.StoreID = S.StoreID
GROUP BY O.StoreID, S.Name -- Added "S.Name" to the GROUP BY list
ORDER BY OrderCount DESC
```

---

Soap box time: The whole concept of the `group by` clause is useless as it is completely deterministic - ie there is only one valid group by expression for a given select list (ignoring functionally identical permutations of the list), so **why is it required**? Why doesn't the query parser just assume it - it checks to see if it's correct, but it can only be one thing, so it's doing all the work required to generate it itself already.

It is ironic that this fact about the language essentially breaks [3NF](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) - ie the group by clause is redundant data in the query itself (it can be determined from other parts of the query). From a data perspective, the language would be considered "badly designed" if measured by its own standards.

Comment: Mostly upvoted for the `GROUP BY` rant :) - T-SQL is an interesting beast... my favourite thing is intellisense that can't kick it until you've specified the subject in the `FROM` clause - kind of silly since the column list comes first!

Comment: Just so I get your comment right. Do you mean that `S.Name` is unnecessary in the group by clause because `StoreID` is the primary key in the Stores table and therefore there can by definition only be one value of `S.Name` for every value of `O.StoreID`?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson no. I mean that the SQL specification requires ta group by clause when aggregated values are in the select list and that the columns in the group by list must be all non aggregated values in the select list. Both the existence and content of the group by clause can be determined by inspecting the select list - ie given the select list you can determine the group by

Comment: Ahh, I had a good answer for you if you meant what I thought :). What you suggests is way beyond what I could imagine. An auto-generated group by clause based on the columns specified in the select clause so you could leave the group by clause out all together and the query would still work. Do you know of any DBMS that does that?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson no databases do this AFAIK, because the SQL spec requires a group by clause and the query parser adheres to that spec. MySQL allows omission of columns and even the group by itself, but the behaviour for omission is non standard (and the cause of many questions on this site).

Comment: Technically, you can group by additional factors that are not part of your select statement, so there is more than one acceptable `group by` per query.  That said, I have never run into a situation where I actually want to do that.  E.g. `Select a, b, count(c) ... group by a` is not correct, but `select a, count(c)...group by a,b` is.

Comment: @aph great point. After reading your comment, I thought at first that returning the extra grouped by value wouldn't be a problem - the caller can just ignore it, but I thought of a valid case where that isn't OK, where you need just one value to build a list, eg "find people whose age is the same as the frequency of any name": `select * from person where age in (select count(*) from person group by name)`. You don't care what group the count is for, and the query will explode if you select it. Maybe this is a case for coding a group by if you *need* to (as here), otherwise auto generate it.

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks!  I couldn't think of a good use for that syntax when I commented, but a subquery is a great example. I definitely agree that most of the time the option to just imply your group by would be great, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  O.StoreID,
  COUNT(O.StoreID) AS OrderCount,
  S.Name
FROM Orders AS O
JOIN Stores AS S
  ON O.StoreID = S.StoreID
GROUP BY O.StoreID,
         S.Name
ORDER BY OrderCount DESC
```

When you use count, or sum etc. function then should be group by all fields, in your case `O.StoreID, S.Name`
for more information

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/group_by.php

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx